# Fetch multiple latitudes and longitudes using geo location

Tags: 6, google-maps

I want to fetch multiple latitudes and longitudes using Google Geo API. I am using the GMap module to render a map in which I fetch business listing address from the database and I want to display Google listing also.
For example, http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=bars;near=chicago&radius=500&output=csv' returns a single latitude and longitude, but I want all the latitudes and longitudes of bars type near Chicago.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you need is a Google Places API integration, and it seems there is nothing yet out there (http://drupal.org/sandbox/lukaswhite/1189440).